# Clickable li keyboard navigation links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a li list which you can navigate using the keyboard arrows, it works fine but I want to be able to click the link using the enter button on the keyboard. I havent been able to find a solution yet.

[Heres the code im using](https://jsbin.com/yifixiruki/edit?html,css,js,output)

```js
var li = $('li');
var liSelected;
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which === 40) {
    if (liSelected) {
      liSelected.removeClass('selected');
      next = liSelected.next();
      if (next.length > 0) {
        liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
      } else {
        liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
      }
    } else {
      liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
    }
  } else if (e.which === 38) {
    if (liSelected) {
      liSelected.removeClass('selected');
      next = liSelected.prev();
      if (next.length > 0) {
        liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
      } else {
        liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
      }
    } else {
      liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
li {
  color: blue;
}

li.selected {
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">First Link</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">Second Link</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">Third Link</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">Third Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

The enter key has a keycode of 13. So, you may plumb in another `else if` clause with the code as follows:

```
else if (e.which === 13) {
  if (liSelected) {
    $(liSelected).find('a')[0].click();
  }
}
```

Comment: this is what i done https://jsbin.com/dodareware/1/edit?html,css,js,output the first link opens the original code page, when i am on a li and click enter it doesnt open the link

Comment: @lanjes -- My bad. I forgot to mention that you need to get the native DOM object to simulate the click. See my updated answer.

Comment: @lanjes -- Please accept the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var li = $('li');
var liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        if (liSelected) {
            window.open(liSelected.children(':first').attr('href'))
        }
    }
    else if (e.which === 40) {
        if (liSelected) {
            liSelected.removeClass('selected');
            next = liSelected.next();
            if (next.length > 0) {
                liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
            } else {
                liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
            }
        } else {
            liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
        }
    }
    else if (e.which === 38) {
        if (liSelected) {
            liSelected.removeClass('selected');
            next = liSelected.prev();
            if (next.length > 0) {
                liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
            } else {
                liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
            }
        } else {
            liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
        }
    }
});
    li {
        color: blue;
    }

    li.selected {
        background: yellow;
        color: black;
    }
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2">Second Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#3">Third Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#4">Third Link</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: this is just showing an alert of the link, how can it open it?

Comment: Updated. Doesn't go anywhere with the anchors now though.

Comment: @TyKroll -- Navigation does work. Your code isn't correct.